# How to access website showing error "mysql server gone away"?

Tags: mysql, web

I am trying to login to a website that constantly showing error mysql server gone away. is there a way to access the website? any hack? any tool? 
[image: here's a screenshot]

Comment: You are accessing it.  The error is reporting that the site itself cannot access its database.  You can do nothing about it other than creating a support ticket...

Comment: Government service running PHP and leaking SQL queries... nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a website is giving you a MySQL error, that means that the server can't talk to the database. If you have access to the server, you can try restarting MySQL or just rebooting the server!

If you do not have access to the server, try contacting the people who run the website and letting them know that you can't access it.